# Get specific SQL Error Code or identify a Lock Timeout with PHP's PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, exception, pdo, mariadb

I am trying to identify a specific SQL failure condition based on the result of a failed query and wanted to know if anyone has done something similar before.

In my example code I am attempting to get a lock on a row in my test table and then handle the response.

```
$sql = " select tt_idno from testtab ".
       " where tt_idno = ? for update nowait ";
$testtab_Lock = $db->prepare($sql);

try {

    $db->beginTransaction();
    $testtab_Lock->execute([1]);
    $db->commit();

} catch(Exception $log) {

    $db->rollback();

}
```

The problem is that I expect this query to fail if the record is locked in which case it is doing what it's supposed to do. Ideally I would like to handle the exception with something like

```
} catch(Exception $log) {

    $db->rollback();

    if($locked) {
        throw new Exception("Locked but everything is fine");
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Panic");
    }

}
```

I was reading through some documentation for PDO's getCode() and tried to use that but it only gives me the SQLSTATE which is close but a bit too generic.

```
} catch(Exception $log) {

    echo "<span>" . $log->getCode() . "</span><br />";

}
```

This gives me the SQLSTATE HY000 but the Error Code I am wanting is 1205 (I'm using the MariaDB documentation : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-error-codes)

Is there another way to get SQL Error Codes or identify a Lock Timeout with PHP's PDO?

***NOTE***

I am using MariaDB (10.3) and PHP (7.2)

Comment: Have you tried reading out the error **message**? Maybe it tells you something more meaningful

Comment: Have you tried `errorInfo()`? It contains driver-specific error code and message: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: wow errorInfo() is exactly what I was looking for, could you please post as an answer so that I can accept it @Icssanches